# Can PowerBI report on the status of a SharePoint site?

Tags: sharepoint, powerbi, metrics

I am exploring the posibilities for PowerBI, leveraging the connected technologies (rather than just making pretty data reports) and wonder if it's possible to interrogate a list of SharePoint sites, to pull out some of the more useful metrics?

I administer many SharePoint sites and (example) would be keen to centralised a report on "available space" for each site, rather than having to check each indiviual site.

Is this possible?

Is there an online resource containing examples?

Comment: The SharePoint admin center has a built-in report for that. https://admin.microsoft.com/adminportal/home#/reportsUsage/SharePointSiteUsageV1

Comment: Unforunately, that doesn't work here; we're paprt of a large coorporation with thousands of SharePoint sites and I would assume that report will allow me to see more than just the sites for which I have access.

Comment: If you're not a SharePoint administrator, you will need to use the Storage metrics page, which is visible to Site Collection Administrators. https://YourTenant.sharepoint.com/sites/yoursite/_layouts/15/storman.aspx 
I have not found a way to load that page into Power BI, though.

Comment: That would be a shame